# Why is the audio duration infinite after recording with a MediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript

The duration property appears only after playing about half of the file. But I need the duration to be immediately known

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cache-eldz0?file=/main.js:0-1075

```
const audio = document.querySelector(".audio");
const btnStart = document.querySelector(".btn--start");
const btnEnd = document.querySelector(".btn--end");

const device = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
const audioChunks = [];
const audioType = "audio/ogg; codecs=opus";
let voiceMessageRecorder = null;

btnStart.addEventListener("click", () => {
  device.then((stream) => {
    voiceMessageRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { type: audioType });

    voiceMessageRecorder.ondataavailable = async (e) => {
      if (typeof e.data === "undefined") return;
      if (e.data.size > 0) {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
      }

      voiceMessageRecorder.addEventListener("stop", async () => {
        const blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
          type: audioType
        });

        audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        setInterval(() => {
          console.log(audio.duration);
        }, 3000);
      });
    };

    voiceMessageRecorder.start();
  });
});

btnEnd.addEventListener("click", () => {
  voiceMessageRecorder.stop();
});
```

Comment: Not at all. In my case, this should be immediately available after the audio playback is complete, because I do not download this file from somewhere, but record locally via a MediaRecorder

Comment: If you're doing the recording, then simply track the amount of time that it takes to record the file.

Comment: If you're playing back the file, and you don't need the duration until playback is complete, then any technique to obtain the time will do, including the technique  at the post I linked.